# I have a Broadcast system for in site talking to users,Keeps right time up till 24 hours. After the 24 hour max the time speeds up

Tags: php

```
$time_ago_op = time() - $comments[$c]['bcttime'];
    if ($time_ago_op <= 60) { $comments[$c]['time_ago'] = $time_ago_op . " secs ago."; }
    if ($time_ago_op >= 61 && $time_ago_op <= (60 * 60)) { $comments[$c]['time_ago'] = CleanNumber($time_ago_op / 60) . " mins ago."; }
    if ($time_ago_op >= (1+(60 * 60)) && $time_ago_op <= (60 * 60 * 24)) { $comments[$c]['time_ago'] = CleanNumber($time_ago_op / (60 * 60)) . " hours ago."; }
    if ($time_ago_op >= (1+(60 * 60 * 24)) && $time_ago_op <= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) { $comments[$c]['time_ago'] = CleanNumber($time_ago_op / (60 * 60 * 7)) . " days ago."; }


    unset($time_ago_op);
```

After it a user posts it keeps the right time in seconds to minutes and hours, Once it hits 24 hours the time speeds up. For example a post that is 28 hours old says 3 days old and such... I am trying to figure out how to get it to keep the correct time and I am not having any luck.. If anyone can help and point out what I have set wrong it would help out a lot. Thanks

Comment: Please tell me you don't keep your code formatted like that in your own editor... whitespace costs nothing.

Comment: @Steven Dirga - It is better to have a brief title and put the question in the body

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are using just pure `if` blocks.  You need to use PHP's `if else` construct.

Further imagine this scenario.   The `third if` block is at the last nano second before it will trigger the `fourth if` block.  The third will fire off, and then immediately fire the fourth, this can/will cause incorrect calculations.

**EDIT**

Why don't you just do something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("bcttime");  // whatever the correct time zone is
$server_time= date('G:ia');
$comment_time = $server_time -  $comments[$c]['bcttime'];
// display the time with formatting
```